# dynamically set value for a radio button with php

Tags: php, radio-button

Hello Coders,
             I have a dynamically created table in PHP and for each row there is a radio button. The intention is that depending upon which radio box is selected, the user can perform multiple functions like, Delete, Amend etc. I can make this all work with hard coded "Value" for the radio button like

```
echo "<td>" . '<input type="radio" name="radioSelect" value="2"  checked="checked" />' .  "</td>";
```

What I am looking for is a way to set the "2" dynamically. For example:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) and $i<=100)
 { 
  echo "<tr>";
      $sno= $row['SNo'];    

      echo "<td>" . '<input type="radio" name="radioSelect" value= $sno  checked="checked" />' .  "</td>";
 }
```

What is the syntax for this? Is this possible at all?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's called concatenation, and you're already doing it with the `.` operator after `"<td>"`, for example.

```
echo "<td>" . '<input type="radio" name="radioSelect" value="' . $sno . '" checked="checked" />' .  "</td>";
```

I'm not sure why you put it that way, though.

```
echo '<td><input type="radio" name="radioSelect" value="' . $sno . '" checked="checked" /></td>';
```

Also, note that only one radio button with the same name can be `checked` at a time, so you might want to rethink what you're doing there.

Comment: That worked...you saved my Friday night. Thank you minitech! The reason is I want the user to perform only one action at a time and on one record only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this ? if you are having a problem in CONCATENATION.

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) and $i<=100)
 { $sno= $row['SNo'];?> 
<table>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="radio" name="radioSelect" value= <?php echo $sno; ?>  checked="checked" /> <?php } ?></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```